# how to set fdir1, mu1, and mu2 in the gazebo tag inside a urdf file

Tags: gazebo, ros-noetic

My problem is how to set the fdir1 for cylinder model.According the gazebo tutorial [ref](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=friction&cat=physics), the direction of mu2 is perpendicular to the mu1, and the first direction is indicated by fdir1. I try to refer to te turtlebot3 description, the fdir1 they used for their model is

```
<gazebo reference="wheel_left_link">
<mu1>0.1</mu1>
<mu2>0.1</mu2>
<kp>500000.0</kp>
<kd>10.0</kd>
<minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
<maxVel>0.1</maxVel>
<fdir1>1 0 0</fdir1>
<material>Gazebo/FlatBlack</material>
```

their wheels pose is
[image]

Does it mean the first friction direction is along x(red)?, what is the second frcition direction? What if I set the fdir1 = "0,0,1", what would happen? Does this mean the friction is not working for this model? Besides, when the robot is moving , the wheel is rotating, the local frame of wheel is changing, does it mean the first friction direction is changing?

Please help me understand this problem! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you link to explains that "fdir1" defines the direction of mu in the "collision local frame". This is **not** the frame of the wheel link. It is a generated frame at the point of contact between two objects.

Note that the parameter is named "mu", not "mu1".

You chose which friction model is used by the ODE physics engine. As explained [on this page](https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=physics_params&cat=physics) the default friction model ("pyramid") has mu/mu2 aligned to the world's x and y axis.

To simulate the friction of a wheel edge in vertical contact with the ground plane, fdir should be "1 0 0". My understanding is that each digit selects a plane for mu and mu2 to apply to: xy, yz, zx axes.

Comment: Hi, what you mean is in default, the direction of mu is along the x axis in the world frame, and the mu2 is along the y axis in the world frame? does the "default" mean we don specify the parameter fdir. You mentioned that "It is a generated frame at the point of contact between two objects", how do we know the whta the generated frame looks like.. could you please explain this with more detail? Or maybe could you explain why the fdir = "1 0 0" in turtlebot3 description, and what the friction direction looks like under this condition.

Comment: I updated my answer. If you want more than this, read the link I provided.